# Running wordcount.jar on hadoop in windows using command line

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run a simple wordcount program on hadoop, but facing an error as below.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/wordcount.jar
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \user\asiapac\bmohanty6\wordcount\wordcount.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
```

I am using below command.

```
$ bin/hadoop jar /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/wordcount.jar WordCount /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wo
rdcount/input /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/output
```

I am using Cygwin, hadoop-0.20.2 with pseudo node set up. I have also uploaded the wordcount.jar to my DFS. See below my DFS screenshot

[image]

I am able to run the same wordcount program in eclipse successfully. I have created the wordcount.jar file via eclipse as per [this](https://sites.google.com/site/tacchadoop/home/word-count-example-part-i---create-your-own-jar) tutorial. I searched a lot in web but could not understand how to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe its a case of backslashes / frontslashes in the path. Not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `/` before `user`:

```
bin/hadoop jar /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/wordcount.jar WordCount /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/input /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/output
```

This makes them fully-qualified paths. If you omit `/` before `user`, Hadoop will search from the current directory.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your effort. As you suggested I added a / before user and tried again. But facing the same issue. :(

Comment: Ah, I think you also need to use `cygpath` to convert POSIX paths to Windows, e.g. `"$(cygpath -aw "/user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/wordcount.jar")"`. `-aw` specifies you want the absolute Windows path. More info here: http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html

Comment: I tried using cygpath, but still the same error persists. Withot using cygpath, I am able to run the `bin/hadoop fs -ls wordcount` which gives me the list of files and folders inside wordcount folder, which is there in DFS. So if system is able to get the path for fs -ls command then why not for running the jar?

Comment: @GoodBoy Because the directory that you're passing, `wordcount`, is the same under POSIX and Windows. Can you try again with `cygpath`, but just specify `-w`?

Comment: I tried with both the commands. `$ bin/hadoop jar "$(cygpath -aw "/user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount.jar")" wordcount/input/ wordcount/output` and `$ bin/hadoop jar "$(cygpath -w "/user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount.jar")" wordcount/input/ wordcount/output`.<br/> But in both the cases I got FileNotFound exception as before.

Comment: Wait a sec... Have you put `wordcount.jar` in Hadoop DFS? And you're expecting it to run from there?

Comment: Yes yes. Should'nt I? I first tried it keeping in my local file system. But then also I was getting the same error. So I tried uploading it into DFS.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. Pretty sure Hadoop can't run jars from DFS. You need to move the jar to your local file system, and use `cygpath` to pass the right path to Hadoop. I assume you're running Hadoop locally?

Comment: Hei.. It worked for me. I tried as you said. I pasted the jar file in my local system inside cygwin and tried with the command `$ bin/hadoop jar "$(cygpath -aw "/home/bmohanty6/wordcount.jar")" WordCount  /user/asiapac/bmohanty
6/wordcount/input/ /user/asiapac/bmohanty6/wordcount/output`. I am able to run the program now. Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: Great, got there in the end :)